# How to obtain the list of current subscriptions on Redis from Java

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

I am writing an application where one process should send the data to multiple subscription channels. The process does not know the channels in advance (as clients subscribe on different topics), so I would need to query all active subscriptions to know what data to to obtain and send.
I found Redis command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> pubsub channels
```

However:
1. It always returns an empty list
2. I cannot find Java equivalent in either Jedis or Spring implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand from your port and based on method documentation `getSubscription()` (Returns the current subscription for this connection or null if the connection is not subscribed.), I think this will help you.

```
redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<Object>(){
        @Override
        public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
            Subscription susb = connection.getSubscription();
            Collection<byte[]> channels = susb.getChannels();
            return null;
        }

    });
```

`Subscription` has the channels that this connection is subscribed with.

Comment: does this help you @nemiga ?